# Bootstrap - how to set content in new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, newline

I just started to learn Bootstrap - I want to get a result like this:

[image]

But without using `<br>`.

At the moment my code looks like:

**HTML FILE:**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="home">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
                <h1>Upper text here <br> lower text here</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS FILE:**

```
#home{
text-align: center;}
```

If I change div `class="col-md-5"` to less than 5 or higher it doesn't help.

Comment: `I want get a result (image)`, Question Not clear!!

Comment: Where is image? you forgot to add i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go..

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="home">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">

        <h1>Upper text here </h1>
        <h1>lower text here </h1>


        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
   #home{
    text-align: center;}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/j9s83skb/1/)

[DEMO WITH MODIFIED LINE HEIGHT](https://jsfiddle.net/j9s83skb/2/)

Comment: When I put <h1> twice, there is much space, other idea?

Comment: @Wojtkovy, I have updated the answer for a changed line height as well.